# Error converting datetime to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am getting an error when I attempt to display a datetime value in a textbox:

My code is:

```
txtStartDate.Text = rdrGetUserInfo.IsDBNull(14) ? String.Empty : Convert.ToString(rdrGetUserInfo.GetString(14));
```

The error message is: *ex.Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'."*

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
txtStartDate.Text = rdrGetUserInfo.IsDBNull(14) ? String.Empty : Convert.ToString(rdrGetUserInfo.GetDateTime(14).ToString());
```

Comment: Do you still need the `Convert.ToString()`?

Comment: Maybe no... I don't have a compiler right here. I think you can convert a DateTime to String directly with Convert.ToString() if it has a method overload for DateTime.

Comment: Thanks that works. Though how do I get just the date, not the date and time?

Comment: Try to ShortDateString() this way: rdrGetUserInfo.GetDateTime(14).ToShortDateString()